# Need to fix a CSV file in NOTEPAD++ Using REGEX to FIND and REPLACE some values

Tags: regex, csv, replace, find, notepad++

Each field is comma separated but wasn't `""`  delimited. Some of the `values` contain large numbers such as `10,203` or `13,415` or `1,214` so basically this is breaking the `CSV` file.

My solution is some `REGEX` magic such as FIND/REPLACE where `[\d],[\d]` to something temp like `[\d]#[\d]` so that I can correct the other `comma` limiters.

I was hoping that i can change (ex: `10,203` to `10#203` or `1,214` to `1#214` all with `REGEX` but unfortunately my current method is returning:

```
Find => [\d],[\d] -> finds 10,203 replace => [\d]#[\d] -> result 1[\d]#[\d]03
Find => [\d],[\d] -> finds 10,203 replace => # -> result 1#03
```

Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex expression: `([\d]+),([\d]+)` and the Replace function in Notepad++ (menu Search => Replace...), like this:

[image]

The captured groups between parenthesis in the `Find what:` field are represented by `$1` and `$2` in the `Replace with:` field.

Comment: You are awesome!! :) Ty so much +1 for the pic.. 40,000 line CSV saved! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

First column: `^(\d+(,\d{3})+),`

Last column:  `,(\d+(,\d{3})+)$`

Other columns: `,(\d+(,\d{3})),`

Note that the commas are included in $0

...This will let you replace with `"$1",`, `,"$1",` and `,"$1"` without converting commas to hashes.